# Probabilities Classification using R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am going to implement Random forest probabilistic classification using R.  Earlier my code was as follows:

```
  data(iris)
 attach(iris)

 # alternatively the traditional interface:
  x <- subset(iris, select = -Species)
  y <- Species

  library(randomForest)
   model = m.rf = randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris, ntree=100)
 cl.rf = predict(model, iris, type="class")
 pr.rf = predict(model, iris, type="prob")
```

But I have found in some places the code as follows:

```
  data(iris)
 attach(iris)

 # alternatively the traditional interface:
  x <- subset(iris, select = -Species)
  y <- Species

  library(randomForest)
   model = m.rf = randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris, ntree=100)
 cl.rf = predict(model, iris, type="class")
 pr.rf = predict(model, iris, type="prob")[,2]
```

I don't know why they put [,2] into the code for calculating probability for each class. In my case dependent variable may have two class or multi class.

I have tried by adding [,2] into my code and its only gives second class probability information and that is not sufficient for probabilistic classification

Can you suggest, which is correct, why many of programmer add [,2] into their code when calculating probabilistic classification.

Answer (score 2):

If the response variable is binary, then there will be only two columns of output for the probability calculation. In this particular case, only one column is needed, as the fact the the probabilities sum to 1 means that the values of the missing column can be inferred automatically. I would hypothesize that the `[, 2]` is a convention for this particular binary case. For your case, which may have greater than two classes, you could choose to keep all columns, or possibly discard the first (`[, -1]`), again relying on the fact that the probabilities sum to 1 to infer the values in that discarded column.

Two reasons one might discard an output column are 1) Saving a smaller output, or 2) if you are planning on feeding the output of the random forest as predictive variables into a further model, as including all the columns from the probability column would lead you into the [dummy variable trap.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)#Incorporating_a_dummy_independent)

Comment: Sir, thanks, it means my first model of Random forest is correctly predicted class probability..